# Discerning "now unfolding themselves into limbless monsters of pain.", verb phrase?

Tags: phrases

> “And I still have other smothered memories, **now unfolding themselves into limbless monsters of pain**." ― Vladimir Nabokov, *Lolita*

What is the grammatical structure and function of this phrase? Do you consider it a verb phrase? It seems to provide additional information for what *smothered memories* (which I'm guessing is a noun phrase) do? I'm not sure I understand the grammatical function of *now*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase is a (non-restrictive) postmodifier for *memories*. It is non-restrictive because of the usage of a comma. You can find more information about restrictive and non-restrictive clauses [here](http://www.kentlaw.edu/academics/lrw/grinker/LwtaClauses__Restrictive_and_Nonrest.htm).

This is the entire noun phrase, with your phrase in bold as a **postmodifier** for *memories*:

> other smothered memories, now unfolding themselves into limbless monsters of pain

However, on its own, your phrase is a **non-finite subclause**. The word *now* is an adverbial complement (of time), the predicate is *unfolding themselves* and *into limbless monsters of pain* is a prepositional object. *Memories* acts as the subject in the subclause.

You could convert the non-finite clause to a finite one, maybe this helps you understand:

> ...memories, *that now unfold themselves into limbless monsters of pain*.

Comment: Non-restrictive and restrictive may seem new to me. I may read on that. Postmodifiers may seem new to me and I may read on that. I guess I mostly got dependent and independent clauses, and dependent clauses like infinitive, noun clause, maybe participle. I guess *now* an adverbial complement argument to *unfolding*. *Unfolding* seems like a participle and I may think it a participle dependent clause?

Comment: *now unfolding themselves into limbless monsters of pain* seems to maybe explain what *other smothered memories* does, and I guess I thought that seeming like a doing, a verb, so I guess it seemed like a verb clause? May there seem something like that? I may not get that.

Comment: A clause always contains a verb, there is no such thing as a 'verb clause'. There are main clauses, subclauses, finite vs non-finite clauses, relative clauses,... If you want to read up on different types of clauses, take a look at this link: http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/clause.htm

Comment: However, *now unfolding themselves into limbless monsters of pain* might be seen as a *verb **phrase*** that modifies *other smothered memories*.